# how to find-replace Unicode character in Google Doc?

Tags: replace, google-docs

The whole problem is that I need editable content of PDF in Lithuanian (let's say in UNICODE), but when I convert PDF to editable breed (I decided to use Google Docs converter) all Lithuanian (let's say some set of UNICODE) characters needs to be fixed / replaced.

Was unable to figure out how to find-replace Unicode character. For example if I need to replace (with match case) `Á` with `Į` it selects all `A`, which is wrong.

It's not the first when Google products are not adopted to life, coze we leave in I18 world, and America with ASCII is not the center of Universe. That's really sucks.

So... how it's possible to to achieve the goal?

Comment: If you are into javascript, you might try to use a browser plugin that allows to do something with your own javascript and make your own search+replace. _I would not dream of using Google Docs for real editing though._

Comment: Unfortunately _not very_, but idea is good. I'm thinking about faster workaround - to download as .doc/.odt/.txt and do everything in Word/Office editor with VBA script for the future.

Comment: `odt` and `docx` are zips with content XML files, so that may prove easy for real programming. But recording a macro might be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Use Notepad++. It has no issues doing such a task. You can just copy paste the results back onto a google doc if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

'Find and Replace' (Ctrl+H) -->
Uncheck 'Ignore Latin diacritics (e. g. ä = a, E = É)' -->
Type your letter in the 'Find' field.

If for some reason that doesn't work, check 'Match using regular expressions' -->
In the 'Find' field, type \uXXXX, where XXXX is the Unicode value of the character. For instance, for Á, the Unicode value is 00C1, so type \u00C1 in the 'Find' field.

Type the letter you want in the 'Replace' field.